# Last date is not getting printed in org.joda.time.LocalDate?

Tags: java, jodatime

This is what is my code to print between two dates and it excludes the saturday and sunday but this one does not print the last date of the given month.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class DatesexcludingWeekend {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LocalDate start = new LocalDate(2012, 05, 1);
        final LocalDate end = new LocalDate(2012, 05, 31);
        LocalDate weekday = start;
        if (start.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY|| start.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY) {
            weekday = weekday.plusWeeks(1).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
        }

        while (weekday.isBefore(end)) {
            String dateValues[] = weekday.toString().split("-");
            //System.out.println(dateValues[2]+"/"+dateValues[1]+"/"+dateValues[0]);
            String date=dateValues[2]+"/"+dateValues[1]+"/"+dateValues[0];
            System.out.println("date : "+date);
            if (weekday.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY)
                weekday = weekday.plusDays(3);
            else
                weekday = weekday.plusDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the out put of the above code :

```
date : 01/05/2012
date : 02/05/2012
date : 03/05/2012
date : 04/05/2012
date : 07/05/2012
date : 08/05/2012
date : 09/05/2012
date : 10/05/2012
date : 11/05/2012
date : 14/05/2012
date : 15/05/2012
date : 16/05/2012
date : 17/05/2012
date : 18/05/2012
date : 21/05/2012
date : 22/05/2012
date : 23/05/2012
date : 24/05/2012
date : 25/05/2012
date : 28/05/2012
date : 29/05/2012
date : 30/05/2012
```

if you see this `31-05/2012` is not getting printed

Please help me to get this solved.

Regards
Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you say:

```
while (weekday.isBefore(end))
```

If you want to include the last day then two choices:

1. Set end to one day after the target date (leave `while` condition as it was)
2. Change the `while` condition.

An alternative while condition would be something like this:

```
while (weekday.isBefore(end) || weekday.equals(end))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in your while loop:

```
weekday.isBefore(end)
```

`31/05/2012` is not simply before `end` - they are equal dates

See the [javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractPartial.html#isBefore%28org.joda.time.ReadablePartial%29)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it because you have used

```
while (weekday.isBefore(end))
```

And the 31/05/2012 is not before the 31/05/2012.

Answer (score 1):

The day `2012, 05, 31` is not before `2012, 05, 31`.

Try changing `weekday.isBefore(end)` to `!end.isBefore(weekday)`